# How to get syncronization lock of a process

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I need to check how many lock(mutex etc) are being used by a process. Anyone know any command on Linux to check it? 
Thanks

Comment: If you can run `ltrace` when starting the process, you can count how many `pthread_mutex_init` entries are listed.

Answer (score 0):

What do you define "use"? Do you mean holding the mutex? A mutex can be allocated in shared memory, and initialized by one process but used (lock/unlock) by another. Basically there is no command can tell in such cases.